# How to collapse React MUI Accordion onblur

Tags: material-ui, accordion, onblur

I have a MUI Accordion in my React project, and I would like for it to collapse when the user clicks somewhere else on the page.

I would like to do this via css, as I am doing the following via css:

```
.focus {
    /* border: 2px solid red !important; */
    background-color: white !important;
}
```

```
                <Accordion>
                  <AccordionSummary
                    focusVisibleClassName='focus'
                    expandIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />}
                    aria-controls="panel1a-content"
                    id="panel1a-header"
                  >
                    <TextField
                      style={{ width: 350 }}
                      id="entityName"
                      value={entity.entityName}
                      onChange={(event) => {
                        setEntity({ ...entity, entityName: event.target.value });
                      }}
                    />
                  </AccordionSummary>
                  <AccordionDetails sx={{ borderTop: '1px dashed black', width: 400 }}>
                    <Typography>
                      Source
                    </Typography>
                    <TextField sx={{ width: 350 }}></TextField>

                    <Typography>
                      Classification
                    </Typography>
                    <TextField sx={{ width: 350 }}></TextField>
                  </AccordionDetails>
                </Accordion>
```

I appreciate your assistance.

I have searched on this requirement, and not found any results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement  `ClickAwayListener` component to detect when a click event happens outside of its child element. And to get the current state of the expended prop you have to add `onChange` prop to your `Accordion` component,  and finally make use of `expanded` prop to set its value (true/false). Please take a look at the code below for a better understanding. also, a working example was added as a link.

Import:

```
import ClickAwayListener from '@mui/material/ClickAwayListener';
```

And inside your function:

```
const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
const handleClickAway = () => {
if(open){
  setOpen(false);
}
};

return (

<ClickAwayListener onClickAway={handleClickAway}>       

    <Accordion expanded={open} onChange={(e,expanded)=>{setOpen(expanded)}}>
      <AccordionSummary
        focusVisibleClassName='focus'
        expandIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />}
        aria-controls="panel1a-content"
        id="panel1a-header"
      >
        <TextField
          style={{ width: 350 }}
          id="entityName"
          value={entity.entityName}
          onChange={(event) => {
            setEntity({ ...entity, entityName: event.target.value });
          }}
        />
      </AccordionSummary>
      <AccordionDetails sx={{ borderTop: '1px dashed black', width: 400 }}>
        <Typography>
          Source
        </Typography>
        <TextField sx={{ width: 350 }}></TextField>

        <Typography>
          Classification
        </Typography>
        <TextField sx={{ width: 350 }}></TextField>
      </AccordionDetails>
    </Accordion>

</ClickAwayListener>

);
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/mui-accordion-clickoutside-kmg1eb?file=/demo.js

Comment: This is phenomenal! Thank you so very much! I am Green with React and this is so very clear and concise!

Comment: @karkiekie you are welcome! happy to know that it works for you, it would be great if you consider upvoting the answer :)

Comment: I tried, but don't have enough points yet. I will do as soon as I can.

Comment: If I add an additional separate Accordion to my page, neither one will work, because I need to somehow integrate a passing of the "id" or "key" of the accordion with your functionality above. In the MUI docs you see this: "<Accordion expanded={expanded === 'panel1'} onChange={handleChange('panel1')}>. I just haven't been able to figure out how to implement both of these requirements. Any ideas on that?

Comment: If I pass in the id of the control inside the Accordion to handleClickAway, now both Accordions will open; however, I only want one to open. Here is what I have, I'm missing something: <ClickAwayListener onClickAway=handleClickAway("Name")}>
and:   const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
  const handleClickAway = (key) => {
    if (key == open) {
      setOpen(key = false);
    }
  };
Should I ask a new question on this?

Comment: Please ignore the incorrect code I put up above in the previous comment, but doing that did help me to find out that that onClickAway event fires even on the initial click of the accordion.

Comment: Just ended up implementing both instead of trying to integrate both into one. Perhaps when I am stronger at React I will do that.  But for now: const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
  const handleClickAway = () => {
    if (open) {  setOpen(false); }};
  const [expanded, setExpanded] = React.useState(false);
  const handleChange = (panel) => (event, isExpanded) => {
  setExpanded(isExpanded ? panel : false);  };
and:  <ClickAwayListener onClickAway={handleClickAway("entityName")}>
                  <Accordion expanded={expanded === 'entityName'} onChange={handleChange('entityName')}>